# RSpec Boolean Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec, rails-postgresql

Test:

```
it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:on_ride_photo).in_array([true, false]) }
```

Validation:

```
  validates :on_ride_photo,
    presence: true,
    inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
```

Errors:

> 1) Coaster validations should ensure inclusion of on_ride_photo in
>   [true, false]
>        Failure/Error: it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:on_ride_photo).in_array([true, false]) }
>          [true, false] doesn't match array in validation
>        # ./spec/models/coaster_spec.rb:96:in `block (3 levels) in '

This is in a Postgres database and the field was defined as follows in the migration:

```
  def change
    add_column :coasters, :on_ride_photo, :boolean
  end
```

and is shown like so in the database schema:

```
t.boolean  "on_ride_photo"
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/179

Comment: Ah right, I take it i'll have to write a standard test to check this then?

Comment: If it's something you think it's worth testing, it looks that way, unless there's been a patch for it. I question these types of tests, though.

Answer (score 0):

I use the `satisfy` RSpec matcher for boolean values.

```
it { expect(:on_ride_photo).to satisfy {|v| v == true or v == false} }
```

Answer (score 0):

What 6ft Dan said works but the cleaner way is to add rspec_boolean to your Gemfile in the group :development, :test:

```
gem 'rspec_boolean'
```

And than use it like:

```
expect(val.is_done?).to be_boolean
```